# File Get Contents

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo una plantilla html con php para enviar una confirmación de reserva al correo a través de phpmailer.

El código está dividido en dos archivos php distintos.

El correo llega, pero no me llega con la información de la confirmación.

Esa información yo la envío al otro archivo a través de un session, pero cuando veo el correo no está la información enviada por el session.

¿Puede ser que al `file_get_contents` no le guste el código php? ¿O necesite algún `return` el archivo *template.php*?

```php
//Base de dades
ob_start();
include ('../bd/dbconnect_create.php');
$sql ="select * from reservas where nom = '$nom' and apellidos = '$apellidos' and data = '$data' and hora = '$hora'";
$re = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row = $re->fetch_assoc()) $reserva[] = $row;

//Nom pdf per adjuntar
$pdf_adjunt= 'carta.pdf';
$template_html_body = file_get_contents('template.php');

//Create an instance; passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
try {
    $mail->IsSMTP();                                //Sets Mailer to send message using SMTP
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Host = 'smtps.aruba.it';     //Sets the SMTP hosts of your Email hosting, this for Godaddy
    $mail->Port = '465';                                //Sets the default SMTP server port
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                         //Sets SMTP authentication. Utilizes the Username and Password variables
    $mail->Username = '------';                 //Sets SMTP username
    $mail->Password = '------';                 //Sets SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                          //Sets connection prefix. Options are "", "ssl" or "tls"
    $mail->From = '-------';            //Sets the From email address for the message
    $mail->FromName = 'Rem La Ràpita';          //Sets the From name of the message
    $mail->AddAddress($email);      //Adds a "To" address $email
    $mail->Subject = 'Justificant Reserva Origens '.date('Y');          //Sets the Subject of the message
    //$mail->AddAttachment($pdf_adjunt);    //Adjuntar pdf amb la carta
    $mail->Body = $template_html_body;      //Body del correu amb la plantilla del html
    $mail->send();
    echo"<div id='loading'></div>";
} 
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "No s'ha pogut enviar el missatge.";
}
```

Comment: Si es un script php `file_get_contents()` no procesará el código. Tendrías que hacer `include` o `require` controlando el [*búfer de salida*](https://www.php.net/manual/es/ref.outcontrol.php).

Comment: Usando el búffer de salida, como sugiere @Sal en su comentario sería algo así:`ob_start(); include('template.php'); $template_html_body = ob_get_clean();`.  Si en `template.php` recoges todo en una variable, puedes hacer simplemente el `include` y luego usar dicha variable.

Comment: Y entonces en el body sigo pasando el $template_html_body?

Answer (score 2):

En primer lugar [`file_get_contents()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents.php) no es para archivos con extensión `.php`, porque está orientado a obtener contenido textual de los archivos. El Manual de PHP es claro cuando dice:

> `file_get_contents()` es la manera preferida de transmitir el
> contenido de un fichero a una cadena.

Si tu archivo `.php` desarrolla una lógica y produce salida por pantalla, entonces puedes abrir el buffer y obtener esa salida en una variable.

Imaginemos tu archivo `template.php` con algo como:

```
<?php
    
    $nombre="El Nombre";
    $empresa="La Empresa";
    echo "Hola $nombre, bienvenido a $empresa";
    // ... Más código PHP
    $mensaje="Texto sacado de la lógica de tu código";
    echo $mensaje;
    // ... Más código PHP
?>
```

Podrías hacer algo así:

```
ob_start(); 
include('template.php'); 
$template_html_body = ob_get_clean();
```

Lo que ocurre aquí es [`ob_get_clean()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.ob-get-clean.php) obtiene lo que `template.php` haya enviado al buffer de salida, y a la vez limpia el buffer. Así, en `$template_html_body` vas a tener todo lo que el archivo `template.php` haya enviado al buffer de salida y en lo adelante podrás usar `$template_html_body`  en tu código:

```
    // ...
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    try 
    {
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        // ...
        $mail->Body = $template_html_body;
    }
```

Si en `template.php` ya tienes las salidas controladas y no emites nada al buffer de salida, puedes hacer el `include` y usar la variable con la que has concatenado las salidas.

Por ejemplo, imaginemos que `template.php` está así:

```
<?php
    $outPut="";
    $nombre="El Nombre";
    $empresa="La Empresa";
    // ... Más código PHP
    $outPut.="Hola $nombre, bienvenido a $empresa";
    // ... Más código PHP
    $mensaje="Texto sacado de la lógica de tu código";
    $outPut .= $mensaje;
    // ... Más código PHP
?>
```

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
include('template.php'); 

// ...
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
try 
{
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    // ...
    $mail->Body = $outPut;
}
```

Aquí, dado que `template.php` **sólo concatenó contenido en la variable `$outPut` pero nunca lo mandó al buffer de salida con `echo`, `print` u otro**, tú puedes obtener `$outPut` al hacer el `include`, y reasignarlo a variables, o bien usarlo directamente o bien enviarlo al buffer de salida.